# How to set button and text-input to same width with other rows in the table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

Inside the first row of a table I place a combination of an text-input and a button. The following rows only contain an text-input field. All rows should be the same width. Take reference on the following screenshots.

My question is how to make button and text box in same size with other rows in the table?

**Current state: ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/36234/))**

[image]

**Desired state:**

[image]

```html
<table class="">
  <tr>
    <td>text:
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" ID="txtDescPoint" CssClass="form-control input-sm" />
      <input type="button" class="" value="..." id="ffcolorswtach" style="position: relative; left: 5px; top: 0px; color: #000000; background-color: #d8d5d5;" onclick="PickColor(1, false, false)" />
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X:
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" ID="txtLon" runat="server" CssClass="form-control btn-sm" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Y:
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" ID="txtLat" runat="server" CssClass="form-control btn-sm" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your jsfiddle is already running with bootstrap!

So why should you use a very old way to layout with tables? Bootstrap already give you a lot of ready-to-go tools / classes which you can use to setup semantic and maintainable forms: ([your updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/36235/))

```css
.form-control,
.input-group {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.input-group-addon {
  min-width:60px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div style="width: 300px; margin: 20px auto">

  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Text</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Button</button>
      </span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">X</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  </div>

  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">Y</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for post.Gerrit any idea how can I make labels X,Y and Text in one size?

Comment: Hey sure! I updated the code block in my answer. As you can see I just added a min-width: to the .input-group-addon elements.

Comment:  great have fun with it :)

Answer (score 1):

try width:77% for input tag,

```
<input type="text" style="width:77%" ID="txtDescPoint" CssClass="form-control input-sm" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.col-70 {
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
            <table class="">
                <tr>
                    <td>text:
                    </td>
                    <td>

                        <input class="col-70" type="text" ID="txtDescPoint" CssClass="form-control input-sm" />
                         <input class="col-30" type="button" class="" value="..." id="ffcolorswtach" style="position: relative; left: 5px; top: 0px; color: #000000; background-color: #d8d5d5;" onclick="PickColor(1, false, false)" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>X:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" ID="txtLon" runat="server" CssClass="form-control btn-sm" />
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Y:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" ID="txtLat" runat="server" CssClass="form-control btn-sm"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use below code to view table elements as your requirement
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>text:</td>
   <td><input type="text" ID="txtDescPoint"
    CssClass="form-control input-sm" /></td>
   <td><input type="button" class="" value="..."
    id="ffcolorswtach"
    style="position: relative;left: 5px; top: 0px; color: #000000; background-color: #d8d5d5;"
    onclick="PickColor(1, false, false)" /></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>X:</td>
   <td colspan="2"><input type="text" ID="txtLon" runat="server"
    CssClass="form-control btn-sm" style="width: 100%;" /></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Y:</td>
   <td colspan="2"><input type="text" ID="txtLat" runat="server"
    CssClass="form-control btn-sm" style="width: 100%;" /></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign `position: absolute;` to that button, `relative` to its parents, use according position settings on it and fine-tune the other settings as follows:

```css
table tr:first-child td:nth-child(2) {
  position: relative;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 180px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#txtDescPoint {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

#ffcolorswtach {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  top: 3px;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #d8d5d5;
}
```

```html
<table class="">
  <tr>
    <td>text:
    </td>
    <td>

      <input type="text" ID="txtDescPoint" CssClass="form-control input-sm" />
      <input type="button" class="" value="..." id="ffcolorswtach" onclick="PickColor(1, false, false)" />
    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X:
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" ID="txtLon" runat="server" CssClass="form-control btn-sm" />
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Y:
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" ID="txtLat" CssClass="form-control btn-sm" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note: I used a `padding-right` on the text input element so the text input won't be covered by the button.

Answer (score 0):

Variation on your layout using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead of `table`:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
}

.flex .row {
  display: flex;
}

.flex .row span {
  min-width: 50px;
}

.flex .row .input-wrap,
.flex .row>input {
  flex: 1;
}

.flex .row .input-wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.flex .row .input-wrap input {
  flex: 1;
}

.flex .row .input-wrap input[type="button"] {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="row">
    <span>text:</span>
    <div class="input-wrap">
      <input type="text" ID="txtDescPoint" CssClass="form-control input-sm" />
      <input type="button" class="" value="..." id="ffcolorswtach" style="color: #000000; background-color: #d8d5d5;" onclick="PickColor(1, false, false)" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span>X:</span>
    <input type="text" ID="txtLon" runat="server" CssClass="form-control btn-sm" />
  </div>
  <div class="row"><span>Y:</span>
    <input type="text" ID="txtLat" CssClass="form-control btn-sm" />
  </div>
</div>
```